# Did a Windows 2000 Standard edition exist?

Tags: windows, windows-2000, windows-edition

I'm completing my list of Windows versions for an error logging system. It's complete from Windows 95 to Windows 8.1, I just have one memory inconsistency in my brain. When checking Wikipedia, MSDN and other sources about Windows versions and editions, I can only find the following about Windows 2000:

- Professional
- Server
- Advanced Server
- Datacenter Server

I believe I have seen a Windows 2000 Standard edition somewhere but can't find much more about it than traces in user comments that are not exactly reliable. Does anybody know more so that I can finally remove that note in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Wayback-Machine there have been only the four MS Windows 2000 versions you listed.

See the following link for reference: http://web.archive.org/web/20000815061513/http://www.microsoft.com/windows2000/guide/platform/overview/default.asp

The snapshot is from the 29th of February 2000, about 14 days after the MS Windows 2000 release. This http://web.archive.org/web/20011201220210/http://www.microsoft.com/windows2000/default.asp snapshot is from the 1st of December, about 5 weeks after the release of MS Windows XP.

I guess that settles it ;)

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Good idea to look at that source. Thanks.

Comment: @LonelyPixel There is indeed no Windows 2000 Standard edition, and the name should actually refer to Windows 2000 *Server* (Standard). Judging by [some official KB articles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555480/en-us), the edition name was wrongly "borrowed" from [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003#Editions), because "Windows 2000 Enterprise Edition" is listed too but that doesn't really exist.